# Method parameter must be obj of certain class that implements certain interface

Tags: java, android, generics, methods, constructor

How to declare a method with parameter which must be same time a certain class which implements certain interface without declaring a special class for this?
Assume i have declared class ImageX and also declared interface Tagging. So I need to create some other class or method which has to receive only instances of ImageX which implements Tagging interface. How to declare such method? something like

```
private void someMethod (ImageX<Tagging> obj){}
```

but this is not correct of course. Yes I could check the obj if it implements needed interface but I want that check in parameters. And what if it is not some method but a constructor...
am I asking about generics maybe?

Comment: So you want to have a `Tagging` interface, and separately an `ImageX` class which does *not* implement `Tagging`, and then you want to have a method which accepts instances of `ImageX` but only if they *also* implement `Tagging`? I would suggest that wanting to do that indicates a need to refactor.

Comment: Yes, I want it. It's about android and the class is Activity which implements some needed interface. But not every activity does it and I didn't want to subclass activity just for that.

Comment: @ stan: I get it. Fortunately, assylias had the answer (and quite a cool one, too).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make the method generic and only accept objects that are both an ImageX and a Tagging by using a type intersection:

```
private <T extends ImageX & Tagging> void someMethod (T obj){}
```

Comment: +1 Niiiiice. I'd want to avoid it, but nice to have it. (Generic methods are just flippin' cool.) If anyone wants to see it in action: http://pastie.org/6179036

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it answers the question but it is not necessarily the best approach as you pointed out!